# how to add PathLine to ShapePath with a Repeater?

Tags: qt, qml, repeater, shapes

**UPDATE 1** - i can get it to work using Javascript - but that seems to be a little bit unoptimized (from 2-3% to 30% load with qmlscene.exe when activated) - complete recreation when the model changes (its not ever growing), is that the only way or is there a more "declarative" style available?

How can i add a PathLine to a ShapePath based on a Model?

- i know how to use a Repeater from outside of Items but not how to implode them inside of Items
- do i need some sort of Repeater-Delegate on pathElements?
- and i don't want to use the LineSeries component

[image]

```
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.15
import QtQuick 2.15

Shape {
    ListModel {
        id: myPositions
        ListElement { x: 0; y:38 }
        ListElement { x: 10; y: 28 }
        ListElement { x: 20; y: 30 }
        ListElement { x: 30; y: 14 }
    }

    ShapePath {
        strokeColor: "black"
        strokeWidth: 1
        fillColor: "transparent"

        startX: 0
        startY: 0

        PathLine { x: 0; y: 38 }
        PathLine { x: 10; y: 28 }
        PathLine { x: 20; y: 30 }
        PathLine { x: 30; y: 14 }

//        Repeater {
//            model: myPositions
//            PathLine { x: model.x; y: model.y }
//        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

[image]

```
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.15
import QtQuick 2.15

Shape {
    ListModel {
        id: myPositions
    }

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    Timer
    {
        interval: 100
        running: true
        repeat: true

        property real myX: 0

        onTriggered: {
            myPositions.append({"x":myX, "y":getRandomInt(0,30)})
            myX = myX + 10
        }
    }

    function createPathLineElements(positionsModel, shapePath)
    {
        var pathElements = []

        for (var i = 0; i < positionsModel.count; i++)
        {
            var pos = myPositions.get(i)
            var pathLine = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick 2.15; PathLine {}',
                                              shapePath);
            pathLine.x = pos.x
            pathLine.y = pos.y
            pathElements.push(pathLine)
        }

        return pathElements
    }

    ShapePath {
        id: myPath

        strokeColor: "black"
        strokeWidth: 1
        fillColor: "transparent"

        startX: 0
        startY: 0

        pathElements: createPathLineElements(myPositions, myPath)
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your _real_ target? Path.pathElements requires a list of elements,  `list<PathElement>`. Repeater also requires some kind of list so what a reason to use Repeater instead of list<>?

Comment: **real target:** i've got a growing list of values containing the cpu load, **reasons for using a Repeater:** i don't understand what you mean with list<> should i use javascript to append PathLIne-objects?, someone told me to always prefere the more declarative stuff in QML, not breaking binding and having the benefit of auto updating behavior

Comment: i hope my model can be used to fill the list<PathElement> so that it gets automaticaly updated when my model changes, but i have no idea how to reach that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use repeater in that element.
The most performant way is to use `QQuickItem` in order to create a custom Item which draws incremental path.
Yet another simpler ways are:

**1-** Use `PathSvg` element and set its path runtime like below:

```
ShapePath {
    fillColor: "transparent"
    strokeColor: "red"
    capStyle: ShapePath.RoundCap
    joinStyle: ShapePath.RoundJoin
    strokeWidth: 3
    strokeStyle: ShapePath.SolidLine
    
    PathSvg { id: ps; path: parent.p }    //<== fill path property using js
    property string p: ""
    
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for ( var i = 0; i < myModel.count; i++) {
            p += "L %1 %2".arg(myModel.get(i).x).arg(myModel.get(i).y);
        }
        ps.path = p;
    }
}
```

**2-** If you know steps, so you can pre-declare all `PathLine`s and then set their values runtime. Just like a heart rate line on a health care monitor.

Comment: thanks for the tips: **QQuickItem**: do you mean implementing it completely in C++ (i think i can prevent that by using a less brute way of filling the chart) **1-** i will try the PathSvg and compare it with 1:1 with my current PathLine implementation (jsut to get a feeling how fast that is),  **2-** pre-declaring is not possible because the list is changing (mostly growing) on the fly

Comment: @llm you can draw just chart line by implementing a custom `QQuickItem`. `2-` it is depend of way you want to visualise data. but I think in your case it is possible. if you want to draw chart each 30px for  x values for example, you can draw whole chart as empty and update whole points in each iterate.

Answer (score 5):

Use an [Instantiator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-instantiator.html):

```
Shape {
    ListModel {
        id: myPositions
    }

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 100
        running: true
        repeat: true

        property real myX: 0

        onTriggered: {
            myPositions.append({"x":myX, "y":getRandomInt(0,30)})
            myX = myX + 10
        }
    }
    ShapePath {
        id: myPath
        fillColor: "transparent"
        strokeColor: "red"
        capStyle: ShapePath.RoundCap
        joinStyle: ShapePath.RoundJoin
        strokeWidth: 3
        strokeStyle: ShapePath.SolidLine
    }
    Instantiator {
        model: myPositions
        onObjectAdded: myPath.pathElements.push(object)
        PathLine {
            x: model.x
            y: model.y
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Shape-ShapePath-Repeater-PathLine, consider using Repeater-Shape-ShapePath-PathLine. i.e. the Repeater creates instances of Shape instead of instances of PathLine:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Shapes
Page {
    ListModel {
        id: myPositions
        ListElement { x: 0; y: 38 }
        ListElement { x: 10; y: 28 }
        ListElement { x: 20; y: 30 }
        ListElement { x: 30; y: 14 }
    }
    Repeater {
        model: myPositions.count-1
        Shape {
            ShapePath {
                strokeColor: "black"
                strokeWidth: 1
                startX: myPositions.get(index).x
                startY: myPositions.get(index).y
                PathLine {
                    x: myPositions.get(index+1).x
                    y: myPositions.get(index+1).y
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Timer {
        running: myPositions.count < 200
        interval: 100
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            let x = myPositions.count * 10;
            let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            myPositions.append( { x,y } );
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADyXicfVJNb4JAEL3zKyY9YT8IaA8NbU+mN020NWl73MoUNy67ZBkaiOG/dxcVQcE5bJjhvfl8PEmVJljSMufrrcM7rjdVkrQS2Xn8Y8NSzJwFixF2Dhib8YzmKkJx8K3xKISkXKiME1cya+IW+yYwQUmwgyIE/xnKECZPUA1jgj1ofBU0PmTyr4Eme1DweADt33dMkRHqVv+JnaczgrdWuaSHoIHUi2hRmtiC0eYsbi0z69ziVAmlQ7j5EWy9vRkAffKINqbNnt9M01e3rxjJ5TLCYuQV/YTvQUJ5QbDNz7g8H+xoxUCqu6CvurXyCuOyfOX0e+1zrXjSuZXOpeQy7rkWvBhZ+CdRSnPkPyasok5RXV8/BNI5NkElV5rHMWo0Qu6uQiBBAa891W6tUi+wpcHOzVa9X6GUdutPzWSkEndUU/xRl9ROzNIUZeRa9d6XUEELelxJ5fwDgewA8A==)

Comment: very late to the party but thanks for your advice :)